# How to get all files from a certain folder with Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, oop, location

I am trying to make a memory game with 16 cards in a Java Swing, I made a folder for all the images needed in a folder next to the java application itself:

> (which is
> C:\Users\edwin\eclipse-workspace\A3 - Java\src\eindopdracht1\Plaatjes.java)

and the Images folder which contains 8 different Images:

> C:\Users\edwin\eclipse-workspace\A3 - Java\src\eindopdracht1\Images

Now I want to put all 8 images twice in an array, using a for loop. For some reason Java doesn't recognize the second file above. Why is that? My code:

```
package eindopdracht1;

import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Plaatjes extends JButton {
    private File[] files = new File(
            System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\edwin\\eclipse-workspace\\A3 - Java\\src\\eindopdracht1\\Images"))
                    .listFiles();
    private File[] afbeeldingen = new File[16];

    public Plaatjes() {

        for (int i = 1; i < files.length * 2; i = i + 2) {
            afbeeldingen[i - 1] = files[i];
            afbeeldingen[i] = files[i];
            System.out.println(files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that `System.getProperty` doesn't do what you think it does. It definitely will not work by supplying a path to it. `File` has a constructor that takes a path. You should drop the `System.getProperty` part.

Comment: If you would have had your path stored in a system property, then it would make sense to use `System.getProperty` to retrieve the path from that system property using that property's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change this lines of code :

```
private File[] files = new File(
            System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\edwin\\eclipse-workspace\\A3 -Java\\src\\eindopdracht1\\Images"))
           .listFiles();
```

to

```
private File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\\edwin\\eclipse-workspace\\A3 - Java\\src\\eindopdracht1\\Images").listFiles();
```